# wordpress replace single quotes with random characters

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have a problem in wordpress website

when i try to use single quote in my posts they are turning it to other **charcters** when i write in the post **"Shouldn't"** it appears like that  **"Shouldnâ€™t"**

i try  adding this to function.php but still same problem

```
<?php    
remove_filter(‘the_content’, ‘wptexturize’);
?>
```

also i tried to convert the whole database to utf8 but the same problem

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing the text, or are you copy/pasting it? I have found that sometimes, depending on the source of text I'm copying from, if I copy and paste the text into the WordPress editor, it will display funny characters. If that's what is happening, one way to remedy that is to type everything manually.